# Пользовательский ComboBox с Таблицей

Tags: c#, wpf, элементы-управления

Доброго времени суток. Появилась задача в **DataGrid** необходимо вставить элемент **ComboBox**, но при раскрывании его чтобы отображалась таблица.
Что-то вроде этого
[image]

При том чтобы в закрытом элементе отображалось значение из первого столбца.
Не подскажите ли как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Исчерпывающий ответ есть на [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43074/WPF-Custom-ComboBox), правда на английском. Ну да код передрать все равно можно :).

Comment: Тут небольшая проблемка с этим элементом. Он почему то не хочет работать на Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Comment: >Он почему то не хочет работать на Windows XP Service Pack 2

ну да, я бы тоже не хотел работать на Windows XP

Comment: Вот вам всё шуточки, а на заводе тут другого и нет. Хотя у меня всё прекрасно работает, но у пользователя крашится приложение при запросе к этому элементу.

Comment: @Пандакун ну блин, вы же должны понимать, что если у вас есть жесткие ограничения на используемые платформы и если перед вами  стоит необходимость написания софта под древние платформы, то придется столкнуться с подобными ограничениями. Скорее всего проблема кроется в версии .NET и соответственно, в поддержке (или ее отсутствии) необходимой версии WPF. Поэтому придется идти на компромисс между удобством и совместимостью

Comment: Дак вот что и странно. Этот элемент работает на Windows XP, где Net 4.0. А на другом компьютере, где всё то же самое, почему-то нет.

Я уже и всё посмотрел и переставил. Толку нет. Все равно крашится. Я уже устал бороться с тем компьютером. Ограничения тут не такие уж большие. В целом всё прекрасно работает.